# HasMany relationship old input

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a model Category. Category has many Localization. When I store Category, I have these inputs:

```
{{ Form::text('title[en]', Input::old('title')) }}
{{ Form::text('title[ru]', Input::old('title')) }}
```

Which I store like this in my controler:

```
        // Gett all inputs
        $inputs = Input::all();

        // Create resource
        $item = Category::create([]);

        // Create localization
        foreach(Input::get('title') as $locale => $title)
        {
            $locale = new Localization(['locale' => $locale, 'title' => $title]);
            $locale = $item->localization()->save($locale);
        }
```

That works great but what is the best practise for updating such relationships? Currently I'm trying that with Form::model binding.

```
@foreach($locales as $key => $locale)
{{ Form::text('title['.$locale.']', $model->translate($locale)->title, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
@endforeach
```

I have no idea how Input::old could work in this situation, so now I'm using $model->translate($locale)->title to get the correct value. Basically the **updating/validation** part doesn't really work. What you could suggest to change to validate such relationship and update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I found a working solution storing/updating relationships with validation. I hope it's the best/simplest way to do that. I created a new array with inputs for validation and changed in the view errors accordingly.

This is my update controller.

```
public function update($id)
{
    // Find resource
    $item = Category::find($id);

    foreach(Input::get('title') as $locale => $title)
    {
        $v['title_'.$locale] = $title;
    }

    // Attempt validation
    if($item->validate($v))
    {
        foreach(Input::get('title') as $locale => $title)
        {
            $localization = $item->translate($locale);
            $localization->title = $title;
            $localization->save();
        }

        return Redirect::action('AdminCategoryController@edit', [$item->id]);
    }
    else
    {
        // Failure, get errors
        $errors = $item->errors();

        return Redirect::back()
            ->withInput()
            ->with('errors', $errors);
    } 
}
```

And this is the update view;

```
{{ Form::model($model, ['action' => ['AdminCategoryController@update', $model->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) }}
    @foreach($locales as $key => $locale)   
        <div id="{{ $locale }}">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('title['.$locale.']', _('admin.title_'.$locale)) }}
                {{ Form::text('title['.$locale.']', $model->translate($locale)->title, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                @if($errors->has('title_'.$locale))
                    <div class="help-block alert alert-danger">{{ $errors->first('title_'.$locale) }}</div>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
{{ Form::close() }}
```

This way you can easily CRUD, validate all types of relationships (input arrays) in Laravel.